# Cambiemos la orientación de uso (extracto) de la etiqueta PHP por una más breve

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, wiki-de-etiqueta, extracto-de-etiquetas

Una de las etiquetas que más visitó es la de [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) pero observo que la descripción o mejor dicho la *Orientación de uso (extracto)* es excesivamente larga. En sobremesa sale cortada y en pantalla de móvil  ocupa más de la mitad de la pantalla. Ya que el texto no se acorta y resulta molesto.

Entiendo que esto debería ser una descripción más breve.

La descripción actual es:

> PHP, acrónimo de "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor", es un 
>   lenguaje de 'scripting' de propósito general y de código 
>   abierto que está especialmente pensado para el desarrollo 
>   web y que puede ser embebido en páginas HTML. Su 
>   sintaxis recurre a C, Java y Perl, siendo así sencillo de 
>   aprender. El objetivo principal de este lenguaje es permitir 
>   a los desarrolladores web escribir dinámica y rápidamente 
>   páginas web generadas; aunque se puede hacer mucho 
>   más con PHP.

Utilizando prácticamente el total de caracteres admitidos (quedan 2).

Propongo acortarla más o menos así:

> PHP es un  lenguaje de 'scripting' de propósito general y de código abierto que está especialmente pensado para el desarrollo web.

Comment: Buena idea. ¡Sugiere la modificación! Nótese que la orientación de uso debe indicar _cuándo_ usarla, luego una coletilla del tipo "usa preguntas para..." ayudaría.

Comment: @fedorqui con lo de la coletilla no terminó de entender que que quieres decir.

Comment: @Xerif creo que fedorqui se refiere a algo casi inexistente, al menos entre las etiquetas más usadas en esSO. Es algo parecido a lo que dice en la etiqueta de [Java 8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/java-8/info): ***Solo preguntas especificas sobre esta versión deben usar esta etiqueta.***

Answer (score 3):

Veo que ya has [sugerido el cambio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/61346). ¡Bien hecho!

En la página de ayuda hay una sección [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) (no traducida [después de más de año y medio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/535/83) :O) que explica qué debe contener el extracto de una etiqueta.

Lo describe en cinco puntos, cuyos títulos son:

> Directrices para escribir extractos de etiqueta útiles
>
> 1. El extracto es el discurso breve de la etiqueta.
> 2. Evita definir genéricamente el concepto que hay detrás de la etiqueta.
> 3. Concéntrate en qué significa la etiqueta en *tu* comunidad.
> 4. Proporciona una descripción básica sobre cuándo usar la etiqueta.
> 5. Algunas etiquetas son de conocimiento común.

Por lo que tu sugerencia de extracto me parece buena, pero tal vez le añadiría algo más:

> *Preguntas sobre el lenguaje de 'scripting' PHP*, de propósito general y de código abierto que está especialmente pensado para el desarrollo web.

Según cómo, podría añadirse una referencia a utilizar etiquetas adicionales, del tipo:

> Añade también una etiqueta con la versión de PHP que utilizas.

Pero no sé hasta qué punto los gurús del tema lo consideráis importante. Me abstengo pues de hacer una sugerencia de edición para no meterme en temas que no son míos :)

Comment: ¿Quizás algo así? **Preguntas sobre el lenguaje ~~de 'scripting'~~ PHP, de propósito general y de código abierto que está especialmente pensado para el desarrollo web.** lo de las etiquetas de versiones no lo veo muy claro. yo quizas la acortaría mas. **PHP es un lenguaje de ~~'scripting' de~~ propósito general y de código abierto que está especialmente pensado para el desarrollo web.** eliminar lo que esta entre **~~** pensanba qu eesto valia para tachar. @fedorqui

Comment: Yo lo dejaría de forma corta pero concisa. y ya en la página de informacion de la etiqueta, añadir lo demas si se cree oportuno. @fedorqui

Comment: @Xerif, publica tu comentario como respuesta; puede que sea una opción para cambiar el texto de la etiqueta de PHP.

Comment: @Xerif aquí en Meta la etiqueta [tag:discusión] tiene el siguiente extracto: _Una etiqueta para preguntas que no tengan una respuesta correcta o incorrecta necesariamente fácil de encontrar. Muchas veces son subjectivas. Si no es un bug o una sugerencia de característica, probablemente es una discusión_. Creo que es una buena referencia del tipo de extractos que pueden ser útiles. Recordemos que es lo que aparece al editar las etiquetas. En cuanto a PHP, sí, _de scripting_ no aporta demasiado y se podría eliminar. Lo de _preguntas sobre_ sí creo que es importante para actuar como ayuda.